# linq to sql: issue with linq query

Tags: visual-studio-2010, linq, sql-server-2008, linq-to-sql

I have two tables

```
EmpInf
    EmpId,
    EmpName,
    Salary,
    DepartNumber.

Dept
    DeptNo,
    Deptname,
```

I also have a `listview1` and `dropdownlist1` which is bound to `EmpInf.EmpName`

While passing a particular query

```
FilterControl.DataClasses1DataContext obj = new DataClasses1DataContext();
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var a = from r in obj.EmpInfs join s in obj.Dept1s on r.DeptNumber equals s.DeptNo where r.EmpName == "'" + DropDownList1.SelectedValue + "'" select s;

    ListView1.DataSource = a;
    ListView1.DataBind();   
}
```

Whenever I select a particular name from a dropdownlist, it returns **No data was returned.** What particular code am I missing or is there any other error?

Comment: Where is it showing `No data was returned`? In the page or is it an error you're getting?

Comment: OK, but where is this message shown? In the page or is it an error?

Comment: at the page sir, while i am selecting the value from the dropdownlist, instead of returning the value, it is returning NO Data Was Returned. i have tried the same query in the sqlserver, it runs there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a breakpoint in `SelectedIndexChanged1` and look at the value of `SelectedValue` to make sure `DropDownList1.SelectedValue` has the Employee name. You can also try `DropDownList1.SelectedText`.

```
string selected = DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString();

// e = employee | d = department
var query =
            from   e in obj.EmpInfs
            join   d in obj.Dept1s on e.DeptNumber equals d.DeptNo
            where  e.EmpName == "'" + DropDownList1.SelectedValue + "'"
            select d;
```

Change this line:

```
where  e.EmpName == "'" + DropDownList1.SelectedValue + "'"
```

to this one:

```
where  e.EmpName == selected
```

OK, my last attempt here... Do this before databinding:

```
ListView1.DataSource = query.ToList();
```

Comment: Sir i want to select the department name as DeptName while selecting the particular Employee Name as EmpInf from the dropdownlist.

Comment: OK... sorry for the confusion. Will adapt the code accordingly.

Comment: sir, already checked that part of breakpoint, but no help, error continue to persist.

Comment: yes sir, i have bound the EmpInf.EmpName with the dropdownlist.

Comment: @ Leniel Macaferi. thanks sir, that particular problem is solved. but as i have used linqdatasource control and provided the controlname to the Listview Id as DataSourceID="LinqDataSource1" and on a same time i am trying to use  ListView1.DataSource = a;
    ListView1.DataBind(); . so at a runtime it throws an exception to use either datasource or datasourceID remove either of them?

Comment: what shall i do make it run, as when i remove  ListView1.DataSource = a; ListView1.DataBind(); it doesn't show any output and when i remove Datasourceid. it still doesn't come with the result..

Comment: Here's a good step by step tutorial that show binding a `LinqDataSource` to a `GridView`: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/07/16/linq-to-sql-part-5-binding-ui-using-the-asp-linqdatasource-control.aspx It's the same thing with a `ListView` with minor modifications. Hope it helps.

Comment: From what I can see in your code: try just calling `ListView1.DataBind()`and remove `ListView1.Datasource = a;`. This is because you're already setting the `DataSourceID = LinqDataSource1`.

Comment: sir, i have declare ListView1.DatasourceId=null just above the ListView1.Datasource=a; and it finally runs  @Leniel Macaferi thanks sir.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the problem here is with your addition of the single quotes on the search criteria in your Where clause:

```
var a = from r in obj.EmpInfs 
        join s in obj.Dept1s on r.DeptNumber equals s.DeptNo 
        where r.EmpName == "'" + DropDownList1.SelectedValue + "'" 
        select s;
```

Assuming DropDownList1.SelectedValue is "Smith" then your generated sql will be along the lines of:

```
SELECT *
FROM <tables>
WHERE EmpName = ''Smith''
```

Notice the double single quotes. To double check this, put a breakpoint after your query is generated and then call .ToString() on it to get the equivalent TSQL. To fix this, remove the "'" from your LINQ query as that will be automatically added for string parameters:

```
var a = from r in obj.EmpInfs 
        join s in obj.Dept1s on r.DeptNumber equals s.DeptNo 
        where r.EmpName == DropDownList1.SelectedValue 
        select s;
```